# How to distribute code and dataset onto worker nodes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I've been working with dataset Movielens (20 million records) and have been using [collaborative filtering](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) in Spark MLlib.

[image: steps of algorithm]

My environment is Ubuntu 14.4 on VirtualBox. I have one master node and 2 slave nodes. I used the released Apache Hadoop, Apache Spark, Scala, sbt. The code is written in Scala.

How to distribute the code and the dataset onto worker nodes?

```
import java.lang.Math._

import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS.Rating
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object trainModel extends App {

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .setAppName("trainModel")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val rawData = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/rating.csv")

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val df = sqlContext
    .read
    .option("header", "true")
    .format("csv")
    .load("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/rating.csv")

  val ratings = rawData.map(line => line.split(",").take(3) match {
    case Array(userId, movieId, rating) => 
      Rating(userId.toInt, movieId.toInt, rating.toFloat)
  })
  println(s"Number of Ratings in Movie file ${ratings.count()} \n")

  val ratingsRDD = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/rating.csv")
  //split data into test&train
  val splits = ratingsRDD.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 12345)
  val trainingRatingsRDD = splits(0).cache()
  val testRatingsRDD = splits(1).cache()
  val numTraining = trainingRatingsRDD.count()
  val numTest = testRatingsRDD.count()
  println(s"Training: $numTraining, test: $numTest.")

  val rank = 10
  val lambdas = 0.01
  val numIterations = 10
  val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)
  //Evaluate the model on training data
  val userProducts = ratings.map { case Rating(userId, movieId, rating) =>
    (userId, movieId)
  }
  val predictions = model.predict(userProducts).map { case
    Rating(userId, movieId, rating) =>
    ((userId, movieId), rating)
  }
  val ratesAndPreds = ratings.map { case Rating(userId, movieId, rating) =>
    ((userId, movieId),
      rating)
  }.join(predictions)
  val meanSquaredError = ratesAndPreds.map { case ((userId, movieId),
  (r1, r2)) =>
    val err = r1 - r2
    err * err
  }.mean
  println("Mean Squared Error= " + meanSquaredError)
  sqrt(meanSquaredError)
  val rmse = math.sqrt(meanSquaredError)
  println(s" RMSE = $rmse.")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to distribute code

That happens when you `spark-submit` a Spark application. Distribution can be per CPU core/thread or executors. You don't have to code it. It is why people use Spark as it should happen (almost) automatically.

> conf.setMaster("local[*]")

That says that you use a single executor with as many threads as you've got CPU cores. That's a local distribution.

You'd be better off removing the line from the code and use `spark-submit --master` instead. Read the official documentation, esp. [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

> ...and dataset into worker nodes?
>   val rawData = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/rating.csv")

The line says how the Movielens dataset (`rating.csv`) is distributed. It has nothing to do with Spark as Spark uses whatever distribution on a file system is used.

In other words, on Hadoop HDFS with 256MB block size (*split*), a file twice the size of the block size is available in 2 parts. That's HDFS to make the file distributed and fault-tolerant.

When Spark reads the 2-split file, the distributed computation (described using RDD) will use 2 partitions and so 2 tasks.

HDFS is a file system / storage so pick any location and `hdfs -put` the dataset. Think of HDFS as any file system you have a remote access to. Use the location as the input parameter of `sc.textFile` and you're done.

Comment: core-site.xml  file is                                                                             <configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  
 </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Did you use `hdfs -put` command to upload the dataset? Please do so, and upload the file to the location of your choice. Use it as the input parameter for `sc.textFile` and you're done.

Comment: Thanks alot for this explanation and your efforts.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: please,Can I use eclipse with scala IDE to run it?

Comment: Sure. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes,I try to run on it but give me error WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 192.168.1.10:7077.Spark Master webui is active and two worker node are live.Why  this error occur?

Comment: Please ask a separate question since it does not seem to be about distributing code and dataset.

Comment: I can't ask because of questions limit

Answer (score 1):

1 - Your dataset is best placed into a distributed file system - Hadoop HDFS, S3, etc.

2 - Code is distributed via the `spark-submit` script, as described here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/submitting-applications.html

Comment: please,can you explain with more details.